# Convert a WinForm application to command line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is an very old Winform application (with a lot of domain logic written in the controllers' event handlers), and I will need to run it in a batch file too. So I added an argument `-gui`, wrapped all message popups to logging if running as without gui, and changed the launching process to

```
if (gui) // Interactive mode
{
    Application.Run(new MyApp(....));
}
else // Running in batch mode
{
    var f = new MyApp(.....);
    f.SomeButton_Click(f, ....);
    f.AnotherButton_Click(f, ....);
    ....
    f.btnOK_Click(f, ...);
    // f.Close(); // Should it be called?
}
```

Should `f.Close();` or any other methods need to be called before exit? I found there are some process hang in the system and couldn't be killed after being launched from another C# application.

Comment: Could you add some more details?For example, what is being done under button click event? May be it will be better to have some static method and call it instead of instantiating form's object and clicking button

Comment: I don't think you can run a WinForm app in that way. Do you get any output at all? Perhaps it is better to separate the functionality that you want to call from the console app in a separate library and call that library

Comment: @Steve, I've updated the question. All the message box and interactive parts have been converted to logging when running without parameter `-gui`. The winform application is old and bad designed so nobody wants to separate the logic to libraries.

Comment: What you have there should work. The click event handler takes arguments `(object sender, EventArgs e)`, so call them with `f.Button_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty)`. Just make sure everything is property initialized. If the MyApp form has items it initializes elsewhere, then you would need to be sure to do that in your code.

Comment: Of course, test it before you go into production!!!!

Comment: @Flater, just removed "is it good enough".

Comment: How are you going to click a button in the command line?

Comment: @theMayer: The code example reveals that he's not clicking the actual button, he's simply triggering the button's click event method when he would've otherwise clicked the button. He's effectively _emulating_ UI control through explicit coding.

Comment: @theMayer, see the `// Running in batch mode` part in the question.

Comment: _The original developers have left the company a long time ago. And the code is not maintained._ - your workaround will make app much more unmaintainable, especially with `-gui` flag. Just imagine that next developer who will touch this app will write exactly same words about you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to call `f.Close()` unless `f.Show()` has been called (assuming it inherits from `System.Windows.Form`).  However, you can do this:

```
using(var f = new MyApp(.....))
{
    f.SomeButton_Click(f, ....);
    f.AnotherButton_Click(f, ....);
    ....
    f.btnOK_Click(f, ...);
}
```

Comment: Right, `System.Windows.Forms.Form` is disposable object and should be wrapped in `using`.

Comment: @ca9163d9, I really hate/love what you're doing right now by wrapping this in a command line, on the one hand its very lazy, and on the other hand, it's very lazy.... lol

Comment: The original developers have left the company a long time ago. And the code is not maintained. Now they want to automate the manual work...

Comment: "The original developers have left the company a long time ago. And the code is not maintained." ~story of my life